# Trackpad malfunction after last macOS update (Sierra 10.12.3)

Tags: macos, software-update, trackpad

I am looking for information / help from someone who might experienced similar issue in the past or has knowledge about the problem described below.

During last week I have been experiencing issues with **trackpad on MacBook Pro Retina 13' Mid 2014**.

It all have started the **next day after latest macOS Sierra 10.12.3 update**.

**Symptoms**:

- not registering multitouch commands, like thumb + 3 or 4 fingers, swipes
- freezes on the movement just to pick up a second later
- stops to respond at all
- moves and send click signals by itself without touching

Some/all of this happen when I try to use trackpad. When left alone, with external usb mouse plugged in, I can use the software mouse without any issue (using external mouse).

I have tried to fix it with:

1. Restart
2. NVRAM reset
3. SMC reset
4. macOS reinstallation

**sadly, none of above helped.**

**Valuable Info**: Apple Diagnostics tool shows that I have problem with memory (PPM002 error code and potential PPM003 and PPM004). Apple code reference page says nothing more about them but to contact nearest Apple Authorized Service Provider.

I will appreciate any form of help.

*And yes... My warranty expired just two weeks ago.*

Comment: Turning off trackpad input in Accessibility preferences helped with cursor self-moving and now I can use Mac with external mouse though the problem is still present.

Comment: Yes, me too!  Still having it as of Sierra 10.12.5.  I also had it on two different machines, a Macbook Pro and a Macbook Air, so I seriously doubt it's anything hardware related.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I still haven't resolved the problem. I think I will visit Apple's Service next week and see what they have to say about it.

Comment: [See my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271558/choppy-mouse-on-macos-sierra-10-12-3-both-trackpad-and-wired/286445#286445) — a permanent "cure" via repeating Recovery Reinstall.

Answer (score -1):

My unrecognized trackpad and keyboard issue fixed after cleaning up desktop. A file was corrupting the start up process.